# How can I drag and drop controls using a common method?

Tags: c#, xaml, drag-and-drop, uwp, windows-10

I have the following XAML code, which creates two stack panels within a big parent Stack Panel. I would like to be able to drag each small stack panel within the parent bigStack panel.

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" x:Name="bigStack">
        <StackPanel x:Name="smallStack1" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="objectManipulationDelta" ManipulationStarting="objectManipulationStarting">
            <TextBlock Text="John Doe"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CEO"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="smallStack2" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="objectManipulationDelta" ManipulationStarting="objectManipulationStarting">
            <TextBlock Text="Jane Doe"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CTO"/>
        </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**C# backend:**

```
private TranslateTransform dragtranslation ;

private void objectManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dragtranslation.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        dragtranslation.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

    }

private void objectManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var stackDragged = e.OriginalSource as StackPanel;

        dragtranslation = new TranslateTransform();
        stackDragged.RenderTransform = this.dragtranslation ;


    }
```

*Original Code found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/touch-interactions#manipulation-events) (Official Microsoft UWP Documentation) but adapted (obviously wrongly) to suit my needs*

**PROBLEM 1**

1) Drag smallStack1 for the first time: OK

2) Drag smallStack2 for the second time: Reverts back to the original position

**PROBLEM 2**

1) Drag smallStack1 for the first time: OK

2) Drag smallStack2 for the first time: OK

3) Drag either of the smallStacks again: Reverts back to the original position

You can check the problems in the .gif below:

[image]

**WHAT I WISH TO ACCOMPLISH**

Drag the controls using a common method, because I plan to dynamically create more controls inside the bigStack panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically reinstantiating `TranslateTransform` everytime you click on an Item. That is the reason why when you click on the item second time, it navigates back to `0,0` which is the original position for TranslateTransform.

To Handle this in a easier way, this is what I would do.

1) I would give explicit `TranslateTransform` to the `smallStackPanel`'s

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" x:Name="bigStack">
        <StackPanel x:Name="smallStack1" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="objectManipulationDelta" >
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock Text="John Doe"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CEO"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="smallStack2" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="objectManipulationDelta" >
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock Text="Jane Doe"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CTO"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And then all i need to do in codebehind is handle `ManipulationDelta`.

```
private void objectManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var stackDragged = e.OriginalSource as StackPanel;
    (stackDragged.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    (stackDragged.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Update**

To add `TranslateTransform` from Code

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I will double-check it when I return home later in the evening. One question, since I intend to create these stack panels dynamically via C# code, is this 
<StackPanel.RenderTransform>

                <TranslateTransform />

            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

something that can be added to the control via C# code? If so, do you happen to know how?

Thanks a ton