# UWP Move dynamicly created controls (buttons)

Tags: vb.net, uwp, controls, move, drag

So UWP is a whole new story for me. Until today i do alot with WinForms. In the past also did some little apps with WPF. I'm currenlty learning al the new stuff from books and the internet, there's alot out there!

However i'm currently stuck at something very simple (at least simple for me in WinForms)

What do i want to achieve:
I have a List of Objects, in this case Buttons. These buttons are dynamcly created depending on the amount of TCP clients. (the app its self is the TCP Server) Now i want a button for each TCP client on the "MainPage". This button simply shows a status through the backgroundcolor and de Click event triggers something simple. So far so good. However i want the user be able to move the buttons across a canvas (or other container) that holds a image, for example a exhibition map. I cannot figure out how to move the button....?? I also know that WPF/UWP does a lot with binding, so i want to use that power. Any tips or snippets are welcome :-)

Comment: How should the arrangement of the `Buttons` be?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281651/how-can-i-drag-and-drop-controls-using-a-common-method/44289411#44289411) answer. In the answer its stackpanel, but you can easily use ManipulationDelta on other controls also.

Comment: @VijayNirmal The arrangement should be as the user prefers.

Comment: @AVK Great, this was exactly what i needed. Got it all working now. This raises a new question though; if i deserialize the button object to disk using JSON are the location point included of it's parent? With other words, i want to restore the location settings of the user when restarting the application.

Comment: You can get the Button Final Position using `ManipulationCompleted` Event. So save those and while loading those buttons, use `TranslateTransform` to pin point the Exact Location.